# Grails Spring Security: Need if/else logic in GSPs based on user

Tags: grails, spring-security, taglib

I'm sure there must be a more elegant way of implementing if/else logic blocks in a GSP based on user info.

Consider the following:

```
<g:if test="(user logged in) && (this users post) && (post replied to)">
    Show options for this post if replied to
</g:if>
<g:elseif test="(user logged in) && (this users post)">
    show options if this users post
</g:elseif>
<g:elseif test="(user logged in)">
    show options if not this users post
</g:elseif>
<g:else>
    show options if no one is logged in
</g:else>
```

I'm having to use the following to determine if a user is logged in (sec.loggedInUserInfo(field: 'id') != "") I know, I hate it!
I cannot use the nice Spring Security tags as they do not satisfy my requirements and I was trying to implement custom tags but would not be able to implement if/else functionality (or could I)?
Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDITED:**

The tag I've created:

```
<g:isOwnerAndStatusEquals post="${post}" status="${Post.REPLIED_TO}">
     My post and is replied to
</g:isOwnerAndStatusEquals>
```

The Tag lib implementation:

```
 class AuthTagLib {

     def springSecurityService

     def isOwnerAndStatusEquals = { attrs, body ->
         def loggedInUser = springSecurityService.currentUser
         def post = attrs?.post
         def postUser = post?.user
         def postStatus = attrs?.status


         if(loggedInUser?.id == postUser?.id && job?.status?.equals(thisStatus)) {
             out << body()
         }
     }
}
```

This above is all fine, but I've no idea, at a high level, how to add if/else to the same tag?

Comment: Yes, you can have this in your custom tag. What hurdle do you face on doing so?

Comment: My issue is implementing the if/else. Thats all!! Obviously I'm just ignorant as to how. I can post what I've tried as an answer?

Comment: You can add to the question instead as an edit. If you are unable to edit your question, then post it in [pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/), I can update the question with the same.

Comment: You are on the right track. You can embed the if/else logic in the tag and then use templates for contents specific to each condition. Based on each condition, you just have to render the template. like `out << render(template: 'abc', model: [foo:bar])`. Have a look at the last example in [Simple Tags](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#simpleTags). Using `render` you can also unit test both the tag and the template separately. Hope that helps.

Comment: Maybe I'm misinterpreting your solution but this example of if/else is not something I need to reuse. The isOwner tag definitely will be re-used but I don't think I want to create custom tags that implement the if/else functionality within them to get this particular job done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following appears to be equivalent to your GSP code and does not require you to write any custom tags:

```
<sec:ifLoggedIn>
  <g:if test="(this users post) && (post replied to)">
    Show options for this post if replied to
  </g:if>
  <g:elseif test="(this users post)">
    show options if this users post
  </g:elseif>
  <g:else>
    show options if not this users post
  </g:else>
</sec:ifLoggedIn>
<sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
  show options if no one is logged in
</sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
```

Comment: Classic case of lamp post here. I've gone with a combination of the above and the custom tags in my edited question but will still have to give the points for @Donal for direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SpringSecurityUtils inside the test criteria of the g:if tag. Like this:

```
<g:if test="${grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils.ifAllGranted('ROLE_MYROLE')}"
```

It will solve the problem since you can combine it with other test. The down-side is that the code becomes somewhat bloated. You can make it look a little bit nicer by adding an import for grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils if you use it at multiple places.